# Unicode characters in Antd column header?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using [Ant Design V2.x tables](https://2x.ant.design/components/table/) and I want to use an unicode charater in the column header, but **how to I do this?** Is there something to take into account for `antd`?

What I tried inside my component's `render()` function:

```js
<MyTable className="table" size="small"
         dataSource={sortDataByDisplayOrder(this.props.DataAsset)}
         pagination={false}
         showHeader={true}
         locale={{ emptyText: 'No suitable records for table found.' }}>
    <MyColumn
         className="numeric-column"
         title={<div style={myColTitleStyle}>\u25b2 / \u25bc</div>}
         render={(record) => (TrendArrow(record.Value))}
         key="Arrow"
    />
```

Instead of rendering the unicode symbol, I see only the uniccode-command.

How it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Instead of using Unicode, use HTML escaped characters. Take a look at this: https://charbase.com/25B2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `{'\u25b2 / \u25bc'}` instead of  `\u25b2 / \u25bc`.